# Unwanted apostrophes in output

Tags: python

I am writing a code to take user input and sort it in descending order. This is my code so far.

```
array = []
array=input().split()

for i in range(len(array)):
    max_index = i
    for j in range(i+1, len(array)):
        if int(array[j]) > int(array[max_index]):
            max_index = j
    array[i],array[max_index] = array[max_index],array[i]

    print(array)
```

The input is

```
50 40 20 10 30
```

The output I get is

```
['50', '40', '20', '10', '30']
['50', '40', '20', '10', '30']
['50', '40', '30', '10', '20']
['50', '40', '30', '20', '10']
['50', '40', '30', '20', '10']
```

What I need is

```
   [50, 40, 20, 10, 30]
   [50, 40, 20, 10, 30]
   [50, 40, 30, 10, 20]
   [50, 40, 30, 20, 10]
   [50, 40, 30, 20, 10]
```

How do I remove the apostrophes and include a new line on the end? I'm new to programming (Have only been learning for roughly 4 weeks.

Comment: It seems that your `input().split()` is returning `['10', '20', ..., '50']` and not `[10, 20, ..., 50]` like you suggested. I believe that changing `array=input().split()` to `array=[int(n) for n in input().split()]` should work as you want.

Comment: Use int inputs instead of string inputs. Your sort will work as expected and your print will work as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're input is outputting strings, so you should add the built-in `int()` function to each item in the input. This would look like this:
`array = [int(i) for i in input().split()]`

To add an extra line to your output, you just need to print out a new line, using the `\n` escape sequence. Your final code should be something like this:

```
array = []
array = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

for i in range(len(array)):
    max_index = i
    for j in range(i+1, len(array)):
        if int(array[j]) > int(array[max_index]):
            max_index = j
    array[i],array[max_index] = array[max_index],array[i]

    print(array)
print('\n')
```

If you enter

```
50 40 20 10 30
```

you will get

```
[50, 40, 20, 10, 30]
[50, 40, 20, 10, 30]
[50, 40, 30, 10, 20]
[50, 40, 30, 20, 10]
[50, 40, 30, 20, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your input is `10 20 30 40 50` which would make you believe that those are integers (`int`), Python's `input` returns a `str`. Thus transforming your input into integers will make your code work as you seem to expect.

```py
array = [int(n) for n in input().split()]
print(array) # Out[0]: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
array = []
array = input().split()

array = [int(x) for x in array]

for i in range(len(array)):
    max_index = i
    for j in range(i + 1, len(array)):
        if int(array[j]) > int(array[max_index]):
            max_index = j
    array[i], array[max_index] = array[max_index], array[i]

    print(array)
```